# Access IMemoryCache in IServiceCollection extension

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, .net-core

I have registered `IMemoryCache` by calling `services.AddMemoryCache()` in my `Startup.cs`

What I want to do do is to be able to use this in an `IServiceCollection` extension method where I add JWT Authentication. The signing key for the token is stored in Azure Keyvault and I'd like to cache the key when I retrieve it

```
public static IServiceCollection AddJWTAuth(this IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddAuthentication(options=>
    {
        options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    })
    .AddJwtBearer(jwt =>
    {
        jwt .TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            IssuerSigningKeyResolver = (token, securityToken, keyIdentifier, tokenValidationParameters) =>
            {
               // Get signing from KV and add it to memory cache
               // Use signing key from cache
            }
        };
    });

    return services;
}
```

What's a good way of being able to do this?

Comment: Be more explicit about what it is you are trying to do.

Comment: @Nkosi I've added details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you need to access what is already inside your service collection, you can use `BuildServiceProvider()` which will give you a service provider with the so far configured services. Note that you must add your memory cache before your `AddJWTAuth` method.

```
public static IServiceCollection AddJWTAuth(this IServiceCollection services)
{
    var cache = services.BuildServiceProvider().GetRequiredService<IMemoryCache>()
    services.AddAuthentication(options=>
    {
        options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    })
    .AddJwtBearer(jwt =>
    {
        jwt .TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            IssuerSigningKeyResolver = (token, securityToken, keyIdentifier, tokenValidationParameters) =>
            {
               cache..GetOrCreate(...);
            }
        };
    });

    return services;
}
```